# Displaying ReportViewer Report on One Page

Tags: reportviewer

I'm running ASP.NET/C# 3.5 with ReportViewer 2005. I'm having an issue where part of the data that gets spit out by the report gets split into pages one and two. The trouble is that most people don't notice pagination in the ReportViewer (I didn't even notice it myself for a while).

Is there a way to restrict ReportViewer so that the report gets displayed on one page only?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A workaround I've found was selecting the "Report" in design view and setting the Interactive Height/Width properties. I adjusted the height to 20 inches instead of the default 11 inches.

Comment: Didn't do anything to the excessive page for me